# Expectation $E[e^{1/2 T}]$ where T is stopping time w.r.t. Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I have some question related to expectation and Brownian motion.

For $a,b > 0$ we define stopping time $T_{a,b}= \inf \{t \geq 0: B_t < bt-a \}. $

I have to show that for $b=1$: $E[e^{1/2  T_{a,1}}] = e^a.$

I am a little bit confused how to start this, because I usually had problems where $T$ is hitting time, but here $B_t < bt-a$, so I am not sure how to do this. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: $e^{B_t -t/2}$ is a martingale.

Comment: @zhoraster Clearly, $\mathbb{E}\exp(B_{t \wedge T}-t \wedge T/2)=1$ ... however, I don't see why we can let $t \to \infty$ (as far as I can see neither dominated convergence nor monotone convergence is applicable). What am I missing...?

Comment: The Brownian motion with drift $-1$, namely $B_t-t$ hits $-a$ with probability $1$. This fact in combination with Girsanov's theorem will give you the formula you seek.

Comment: @saz , zhoraster I also tried to start with the fact that $e^{B_t - t/2}$ is martingale, but I don't know how would I come to wanted result of $e^a$. 

Jown Dawnkins This first part it is clear to me. Could you explain a little bit more how would I use Girsanov's theorem on this in particular? Thanks.

Comment: @saz I don't know if I understood your question okay, but I don't think you would need to send $t \to \infty $. You can only use the fact that $e^{B_t - t/2}$ is martingale and than use optional stopping theorem which says that $E[e^{B_T -T/2}] = E[e^{B_0 - 0}]=1.$ But now that I know this, I still don't know how would that get me to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elaboration:** Abbreviate $T=T_{a,1}$ and $Z_t=\exp(B_t-t/2)$. There is no doubt that $P[T<\infty]=1$. Because $Z=(Z_t)$ is a martingale, so too is $Z$ stopped at time $T$; because $Z_0=1$,
$$
1=E[Z_{T\wedge t}]=E[e^{T/2-a};T\le t]+E[e^{B-t-t/2}; t<T].
$$
The first term on the right side of this display converges to $E[e^{T/2-a}]$ as $t$ increases to $+\infty$ by monotone convergence. It remains to show that the second term converges to $0$. By Girsanov's theorem, because $Z_t1_{\{t<T\}}$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable,
$$
E[e^{B_t-t/2};t<T]=E[Z_t; t<T]=Q[t<T],
$$
where $Q$ is the law of the Brownian motion with drift +1 (that is, the law of $B_t+t$). Thus
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}E[e^{B_t-t/2};t<T]= Q[T=+\infty].
$$
Finally, $Q[T=+\infty]=0$, because the hitting timeof the boundary $t-a$ by a Brownian motion with unit positive drift has the same distribution as the hitting time of $-a$ by a standard Brownian motion, and the latter hitting time is finite, a.s.